# GWT SerializationException for com.google.gwt.view.client.Range

Tags: java, gwt

I get this problem intermittently on a Tomcat 7 server.  Most of the time it works and does not seem related to code changes.  E.g. today the server was restarted and we started seeing the problem with the exact same war from the last 2 weeks.  It's been observed with GWT 2.6 and 2.7

> `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.google.gwt.view.client.Range' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Range(0,20)`

It has a javadoc for the null constructor referencing RPC:

```java
/**
 * The range of interest for a single handler.
 */
public class Range implements Serializable {

   private int length;
   private int start;

   ...

   /**
    * Used by RPC.
    */
    Range() {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For classes, which are used for communication between server and client in GWT I would recommend to use [IsSerializable](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) instead of Serializable.

Have you tried that and does the problem persist?

Comment: It's a GWT class: com.google.gwt.view.client.Range  Was considering extending it and making it IsSerializable

Comment: Oh, that is a built-in type of GWT. So this should not happen at all. I thought this happens during compilation of your GWT project. Maybe some of the GWT classes in the WAR file are corrupted on your server.

You could try to undeploy the WAR archive in Tomcat, restart the server and the redeploy it.
Furthermore the Tomcat error logs might give you a hint.

Comment: The client gets a 500 and the snippet above is the server log.  I should try the [GWT forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit)